# windows app store access to user email

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to create a feedback form for users to give feedback for the app.  Is there access to the users email address from the app?  can the app ask for permissions?  If I don't have access how can i hyperlink to the users email client for a windows8 app store app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open up the users mail client you can do something like this:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:support@email.co.uk?subject=App Feedback"));
```

That's what I've used for our support link and it opened up the Mail app with the subject set correctly :o)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the user's email address by getting the principal name - this is documented to be typically the address but you cant be sure so use an email validator to check If its actually the email address. If not prompt the user to enter it for you.

```
var principalName = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is ask them for their email address or use the Contact Picker. Like John mentioned you may be able to get a valid email address from the display name but do not rely on this to be true as its not an email address field.