# How to get the currently logged in user's email-id in a windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

How can i fetch the currently logged in user's email id from a windows store app?

I tried Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation class but it doesn't have a method to do so. Some methods are access denied and can not be used.
How do i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows app store access to user email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717626/windows-app-store-access-to-user-email)

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate. The question is not about opening the email client but retrieving the email address instead. The non-accepted answers in the linked question should be helpful, though.